# How to use/document a ggplot2 special variable ..count.. in an R Package

Tags: r, ggplot2, roxygen2

I'm creating a package for reporting data using ggplot2. I'm using the variable `..count..` but the R CMD Check notes the existence of this variable:

```
report <- function(df, a){
  ggplot2::ggplot(df, 
                  ggplot2::aes(x = a)) +
    ggplot2::geom_histogram(
      ggplot2::aes(fill = ..count..))
}
df2 <- data.frame(b = rnorm(100,10,1))
report(df2, df2$b)
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You could replace the double dot with `calc`.  Check [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/2184d962b2326ffab0cec4977b22795df004c149/R/aes-calculated.r)

Comment: Thanks. however, if I use, `ggplot(mpg, aes(displ)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = calc(count)))` I still have to document 'count' and i will have a note in R CMD Check